# Error when trying to import csv file as a table into MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I get the following error when trying to import a CSV file as a table (even if I change the encoding to latin1 or latin2):[image]

Comment: The simplest solution for this would be to open the source .csv in a text editor that reveals these characters, such as Sublime Text, then eliminate or replace the `<0xc3>` codes. You can then confirm the file encoding is set to UTF-8 (or something else you prefer) and perform the import 